Value object with linq cannot do contains method
I'm using EF Core 8 with an Oracle database.
I'm trying to do a select of data where a value is contained in a column. The SQL statement would be like :
SELECT * 
FROM TASKS 
WHERE NAME LIKE "%Task%"

I have the following linq code (Name is a ValueObject of type string):
 List<TaskEntity> tasks = await _dbSet.Where(x => x.Name.Value.Contains("Task"))
                                      .ToListAsync();

And the entity
public partial class TaskEntity 
{
    public DatabaseTableId Id { get; set; }
    public Name Name { get; set; }
}

But I'm getting this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression
'DbSet()
.Where(t => t.Name.Value.Contains("Task"))' could not be translated.

The model builder:
modelBuilder.Entity<TaskEntity>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

    entity.ToTable("TASKS");

    entity.Property(e => e.Id)
        .HasConversion<DatabaseTableIdConverter>()
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
        .HasColumnName("ID");
    entity.Property(e => e.Name)
        .HasConversion<NameConverter>()
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .HasColumnName("NAME");
});

Name VO (simplified):
public class Name
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public Name(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Name), "Name cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        Value = value;
    }
}

Name converter:
public class NameConverter : ValueConverter<Name, string>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a <see cref="Name"/> to a <see cref="string"/> value to use it in EF
    /// </summary>
    public NameConverter() : base
    (
        Name => Name.Value,
        value => new Name(value))
    { }
}

I've tried everything, a contains method in the valueobject using EF.Function.Like...  with FromSqlRaw does work but I need the IQueryable.

The error is clear and very well documented. LINQ can't translate arbitrary client-side function calls into SQL and Name is an unknown class with an unknown property Value. Are you trying to use some "best practices" by wrapping properties in other classes? There's no ValueObject in EF or LINQ. NameConverter tells EF how to convert values from the text column Name to your own custom class, it doesn't specify how operations on that custom class can be translated to SQL

Besides, using Contains is a bad practice. It generates a LIKE '%abc%' clause that can't use any indexes and forces the database to scan the entire table for matches. That's why applications use either StartsWith or use full text search indexes to search for specific words or variations in a field

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying to get the same result as SELECT * FROM TASKS WHERE NAME LIKE "%Task%"

Consider using EF Core's complex types for value objects.

@PanagiotisKanavos Name is a single value VO so whats the diference of using a converter and having the complexType?

Please add the code of Name and NameConverter.

@PanagiotisKanavos i changed the model builder to use complex types, the contains method is still not working, same error

@GertArnold i added the code

Complex types work. The samples and examples work. Your attempt to force your own DDD-like custom implementation on EF won't work, because EF simply has no idea what your custom code does. The code you posted hasn't fixed the problem at all, it's still the same unknown custom type

@PanagiotisKanavos i changed in my own code (i havent updated the question with the new code) the model builder to instead of using the converter uses the ownsOne, and then i tried to use the contains method and i get the same error

The real problem is that you're trying to apply "best practices" without understanding what's going on. Right now you're trying to alias a primitive type because ... why? I understand specifying a Name type in the database with its own CHECKs, I understand wanting to create such checks automatically, either as type checks or triggers. Some of these things are possible with EF, some not.

@marcosagni98 i changed in my own code did you read the link I posted? No converter is necessary when you use a complex type. No Value property is needed or even allowed. You don't need a custom constructor if you use record. This may not work with a single-property ... property but it does work with meaningful complex types.  ComplexProperty won't make EF work with your custom, unknown type. You'll have to write custom extensions like eg those created by NpgSql to handle spatial data, or map JSON fields to complex objects

@PanagiotisKanavos Are you suggesting that it's better not to use Entity Framework Core for this scenario, or are you suggesting that I should use primitives on the entity and map the Value Object  data to the entity in the repository? In other words, should I use EF with primitives and then map the VO data to the entity, or should I not use EF at all?

@marcosagni98, Properties with converters cannot be used in LINQ Queries, exception is when you just compare x.Name = "SomeName". Maybe it can be done with Query interceptor, but i'm not sure.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv considering having the Entity with primative values and mapping the DTO that have the VO to it, I´m using contains of List<> without any problem comparing VO to VO but in this context I have tried everything for 2 days and I think I'm on a dead end

You can enhance your Name class by adding implicit conversion operators:
public class Name
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public Name(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Name), "Name cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(Name name) => name.Value;
    public static implicit operator Name(string value) => new Name(value);
}

This allows you to use explicit casting when querying:
List<TaskEntity> tasks = await _dbSet
  .Where(x => ((string)x.Name).Contains("Task"))
  .ToListAsync();

This has been tested with EF Core 8.

Works just as expected thanks!
